# Wamp Server on local machine responds to ping but port 80 comes up as closed

Tags: url, apache, godaddy, wampserver, ping

I recently registered the domain `politicsapp.us` with GoDaddy and I am trying to set up a server on my local machine with WampServer. I set it all up, but when i type that into a browser, it gives me `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

I first tried to ping the URL and got the following response

```
C:\Users\Admin>ping politicsapp.us

Pinging politicsapp.us [71.228.29.37] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 71.228.29.37: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=63
Reply from 71.228.29.37: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=63
Reply from 71.228.29.37: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=63
Reply from 71.228.29.37: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=63

Ping statistics for 71.228.29.37:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 10ms, Maximum = 18ms, Average = 13ms

C:\Users\Admin>
```

So ping works. And the domain is pointing to the right place. I checked my router and port 80 is in fact forwarding to this machine. But [PortChecker](http://portchecker.co/check) is telling me that my port is closed. I have added a rule to allow all incoming port 80 connections in Windows Firewall.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Edit

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

and replace

```
::1 localhost
```

with

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Save and restart apache. Hope it will work .